# Highest Posterior Density Region and Central Credible Region

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, statsmodels, pymc

Given a posterior p(Θ|D) over some parameters Θ, one can [define](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262018020) the following:

### Highest Posterior Density Region:

The **Highest Posterior Density Region** is the set of most probable values of Θ that, in total, constitute 100(1-α) % of the posterior mass.

In other words, for a given α, we look for a *p** that satisfies:

[image]

and then obtain the **Highest Posterior Density Region** as the set:

[image]

### Central Credible Region:

Using the same notation as above, **a Credible Region** (or interval) is defined as:

[image]

Depending on the distribution, there could be many such intervals. **The central credible interval** is defined as a credible interval where there is **(1-α)/2** mass on **each tail**.

### Computation:

- For general distributions, given samples from the distribution, are there any built-ins in to obtain the two quantities above in Python or **[PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc)**?
- For common parametric distributions (e.g. Beta, Gaussian, etc.) are there any built-ins or libraries to compute this using [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) or [statsmodels](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/)?

Comment: Why the close vote? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: confidence intervals come from frequentist inference; posterior distribution is the bayesian approach; these are very different paradigms; what is the point of mixing them together?

Comment: @behzad.nouri - nowhere in my post I mentioned confidence intervals. Both credible and HPD regions are Bayesian.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To calculate HPD you can leverage pymc3, Here is an example

```
import pymc3
from scipy.stats import norm
a = norm.rvs(size=10000)
pymc3.stats.hpd(a)
```

Comment: If you want to use pymc:
import pymc as pm
pm.utils.hpd(a, alpha=0.025).

The docstring says:
"""Calculate highest posterior density (HPD) of array for given alpha. The HPD is the
    minimum width Bayesian credible interval (BCI).
    :Arguments:
      x : Numpy array
          An array containing MCMC samples
      alpha : float
          Desired probability of type I error
    """

Comment: I like this simple solution for RVS data. Does PyMC3 happen to have an analytical solution? (i.e, where input is: confidence interval `alpha`, successes `a`, failures `b`) and output is the min and max credible interval limits? 

I posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008346/analytic-highest-density-interval-in-python-preferably-for-beta-functions).

Comment: I am not aware of this

Comment: For anyone looking into this with a recent version of pymc3: you want to use `pymc3.stats.hdi`.

Answer (score 25):

From my understanding "central credible region" is not any different from how confidence intervals are calculated; all you need is the inverse of `cdf` function at `alpha/2` and `1-alpha/2`; in `scipy` this is called `ppf` ( percentage point function ); so as for Gaussian posterior distribution:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> alpha = .05
>>> l, u = norm.ppf(alpha / 2), norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2)
```

to verify that `[l, u]` covers `(1-alpha)` of posterior density:

```
>>> norm.cdf(u) - norm.cdf(l)
0.94999999999999996
```

similarly for Beta posterior with say `a=1` and `b=3`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import beta
>>> l, u = beta.ppf(alpha / 2, a=1, b=3), beta.ppf(1 - alpha / 2, a=1, b=3)
```

and again:

```
>>> beta.cdf(u, a=1, b=3) - beta.cdf(l, a=1, b=3)
0.94999999999999996
```

[here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions) you can see parametric distributions that are included in scipy; and I guess all of them have `ppf` function;

As for highest posterior density region, it is more tricky, since `pdf` function is not necessarily invertible; and in general such a region may not even be connected; for example, in the case of Beta with `a = b = .5` ( as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Beta_distribution_pdf.svg));

But, in the case of Gaussian distribution, it is easy to see that "Highest Posterior Density Region" coincides with "Central Credible Region"; and I think that is is the case for all symmetric uni-modal distributions ( i.e. if pdf function is symmetric around the mode of distribution)

A possible numerical approach for the general case would be binary search over the value of `p*` using [numerical integration](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) of `pdf`; utilizing the fact that the integral is a monotone function of `p*`;

---

Here is an example for mixture Gaussian:

**[ 1 ]** First thing you need is an analytical pdf function; for mixture Gaussian that is easy:

```
def mix_norm_pdf(x, loc, scale, weight):
    from scipy.stats import norm
    return np.dot(weight, norm.pdf(x, loc, scale))
```

so for example for location, scale and weight values as in

```
loc    = np.array([-1, 3])   # mean values
scale  = np.array([.5, .8])  # standard deviations
weight = np.array([.4, .6])  # mixture probabilities
```

you will get two nice Gaussian distributions holding hands:

[image]

---

**[ 2 ]** now, you need an error function which given a test value for `p*` integrates pdf function above `p*` and returns squared error from the desired value `1 - alpha`:

```
def errfn( p, alpha, *args):
    from scipy import integrate
    def fn( x ):
        pdf = mix_norm_pdf(x, *args)
        return pdf if pdf > p else 0

    # ideally integration limits should not
    # be hard coded but inferred
    lb, ub = -3, 6 
    prob = integrate.quad(fn, lb, ub)[0]
    return (prob + alpha - 1.0)**2
```

---

**[ 3 ]** now, for a given value of `alpha` we can minimize the error function to obtain `p*`:

```
alpha = .05

from scipy.optimize import fmin
p = fmin(errfn, x0=0, args=(alpha, loc, scale, weight))[0]
```

which results in `p* = 0.0450`, and HPD as below; the red area represents `1 - alpha` of the distribution, and the horizontal dashed line is `p*`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @behzad.nouri -- If we assume that the Normal distribution in your code refers to the posterior of `Θ` (as I assumed in the OP) then, what you are computing above is the **central credible region** and not a **confidence interval**.

Comment: @user815423426 i am just saying the computation is similar to how confidence intervals are calculated, ( in the sense that you look at inverse cdf function );

Comment: That is correct. Thanks. I'm definitely interested in the last sentence of your answer. Assuming e.g. a mix. of two Gaussians, would you mind elaborating further on the computation of the HPD using integration methods from SciPy?

Comment: @user815423426 i will edit my answer to include more details when i get the chance

Comment: thanks for sharing! note that this is Equal Tail credible intervals (as opposed to High Density credible intervals, see `HDIofICDF` on this page)!

Comment: Please note that for skewed distributions your claim that " all you need is the inverse of cdf function at alpha/2 and 1-alpha/2'" to calculate the highest density interval is wrong. What your suggestion gives you is an equal-tailed interval (ETI) - which depending on the shape of your distribution may not be identical to the HDI (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/highest-density-interval for details)

Answer (score 12):

Another option (adapted from R to Python) and taken from the book Doing bayesian data analysis by John K. Kruschke) is the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
from scipy.stats import *

def HDIofICDF(dist_name, credMass=0.95, **args):
    # freeze distribution with given arguments
    distri = dist_name(**args)
    # initial guess for HDIlowTailPr
    incredMass =  1.0 - credMass

    def intervalWidth(lowTailPr):
        return distri.ppf(credMass + lowTailPr) - distri.ppf(lowTailPr)

    # find lowTailPr that minimizes intervalWidth
    HDIlowTailPr = fmin(intervalWidth, incredMass, ftol=1e-8, disp=False)[0]
    # return interval as array([low, high])
    return distri.ppf([HDIlowTailPr, credMass + HDIlowTailPr])
```

The idea is to create a function *intervalWidth* that returns the width of the interval that
starts at lowTailPr and has *credMass* mass. The minimum of the intervalWidth function is founded by using the [fmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) minimizer from scipy.

For example the result of:

```
print HDIofICDF(norm, credMass=0.95, loc=0, scale=1)
```

is

```
    [-1.95996398  1.95996398]
```

The name of the distribution parameters passed to HDIofICDF, must be exactly the same used in scipy.

Comment: This is a really nice solution for unimodal distributions found in scipy. The code style makes me twitch a little, but the simplicity of your answer wins the day.

Comment: Please do clarify which problem you're solving: a restricted version of the original question: the Highest Posterior Density Region **restricted to uni-modal distributions**?

Comment: I love this solution and have been using for a while now and have stress tested it. I would, however like to ask if this could be optimised somehow for many runs? I'm keen for the `scipy.stats.beta` A factor 10X faster in python would be brilliant! (note that I have seen the equal tail ETI solution which is quick, but does not serve the same purpose as HDI). 

I posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008346/analytic-highest-density-interval-in-python-preferably-for-beta-functions) on this specific use case.

Answer (score 9):

PyMC has a built in function for computing the hpd. In v2.3 it's in utils. See the source [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/2.3/pymc/utils.py). As an example of a linear model and it's HPD

```
import pymc as pc  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
## data
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.array(range(0,50))
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=40.0, size=50)
y = 2*x+y
## plt.scatter(x,y)

## priors
emm = pc.Uniform('m', -100.0, 100.0, value=0)
cee = pc.Uniform('c', -100.0, 100.0, value=0) 

#linear-model
@pc.deterministic(plot=False)
def lin_mod(x=x, cee=cee, emm=emm):
    return emm*x + cee 

#likelihood
llhy = pc.Normal('y', mu=lin_mod, tau=1.0/(10.0**2), value=y, observed=True)

linearModel = pc.Model( [llhy, lin_mod, emm, cee] )
MCMClinear = pc.MCMC( linearModel)
MCMClinear.sample(10000,burn=5000,thin=5)
linear_output=MCMClinear.stats()

## pc.Matplot.plot(MCMClinear)
## print HPD using the trace of each parameter 
print(pc.utils.hpd(MCMClinear.trace('m')[:] , 1.- 0.95))
print(pc.utils.hpd(MCMClinear.trace('c')[:] , 1.- 0.95))
```

You may also consider calculating the quantiles

```
print(linear_output['m']['quantiles'])
print(linear_output['c']['quantiles'])
```

where I think if you just take the 2.5% to 97.5% values you get your 95% central credible interval.

Comment: FYI the docstring for the function is:

"""Calculate highest posterior density (HPD) of array for given alpha. The HPD is the
    minimum width Bayesian credible interval (BCI).
    :Arguments:
      x : Numpy array
          An array containing MCMC samples
      alpha : float
          Desired probability of type I error
    """

Comment: I tried this in Python 3. I installed these: `pip install numpy pymc matplotlib pymc scipy`

From the `linear_output=MCMClinear.stats()` statement, I get `Could not generate output statistics for c
Could not generate output statistics for lin_mod
Could not generate output statistics for m
The HPD prints are:
[1.96582851 2.31984871]
[10.0042424  20.72279348]`

The lines like `print(linear_output['m']['quantiles'])` say: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.
Not sure how to interpret that...

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled across this post trying to find a way to estimate an HDI from an MCMC sample but none of the answers worked for me.
Like aloctavodia, I adapted an R example from the book Doing Bayesian Data Analysis to Python. I needed to compute a 95% HDI from an MCMC sample. Here's my solution:

```
import numpy as np
def HDI_from_MCMC(posterior_samples, credible_mass):
    # Computes highest density interval from a sample of representative values,
    # estimated as the shortest credible interval
    # Takes Arguments posterior_samples (samples from posterior) and credible mass (normally .95)
    sorted_points = sorted(posterior_samples)
    ciIdxInc = np.ceil(credible_mass * len(sorted_points)).astype('int')
    nCIs = len(sorted_points) - ciIdxInc
    ciWidth = [0]*nCIs
    for i in range(0, nCIs):
    ciWidth[i] = sorted_points[i + ciIdxInc] - sorted_points[i]
    HDImin = sorted_points[ciWidth.index(min(ciWidth))]
    HDImax = sorted_points[ciWidth.index(min(ciWidth))+ciIdxInc]
    return(HDImin, HDImax)
```

The method above is giving me logical answers based on the data I have!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the central credible interval in two ways: Graphically, when you call `summary_plot` on variables in your model, there is an `bpd` flag that is set to `True` by default. Changing this to `False` will draw the central intervals. The second place you can get it is when you call the `summary` method on your model or a node; it will give you posterior quantiles, and the outer ones will be 95% central interval by default (which you can change with the `alpha` argument).

Answer (score 1):

#### In `R` you can use the `stat.extend` package

If you are dealing with standard parametric distributions, and you don't mind using `R`, then you can use the HDR functions in the [`stat.extend` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stat.extend/index.html).  This package has HDR functions for all the base distributions and some of the distributions in extension packages.  It computes the HDR using the quantile function for the distribution, and automatically adjusts for the shape of the distribution (e.g., unimodal, bimodal, etc.).  Here are some examples of HDRs computed with this package for standard parametric distributions.

```
#Load library
library(stat.extend)

#---------------------------------------------------------------
#Compute HDR for gamma distribution
HDR.gamma(cover.prob = 0.9, shape = 3, scale = 4)

        Highest Density Region (HDR) 
 
90.00% HDR for gamma distribution with shape = 3 and scale = 4 
Computed using nlm optimisation with 6 iterations (code = 1) 

[1.76530758147504, 21.9166988492762]

#---------------------------------------------------------------
#Compute HDR for (unimodal) beta distribution
HDR.beta(cover.prob = 0.9, shape1 = 3.2, shape2 = 3.0)

        Highest Density Region (HDR) 
 
90.00% HDR for beta distribution with shape1 = 3.2 and shape2 = 3 
Computed using nlm optimisation with 4 iterations (code = 1) 

[0.211049233508331, 0.823554556452285]

#---------------------------------------------------------------
#Compute HDR for (bimodal) beta distribution
HDR.beta(cover.prob = 0.9, shape1 = 0.3, shape2 = 0.4)

        Highest Density Region (HDR) 
 
90.00% HDR for beta distribution with shape1 = 0.3 and shape2 = 0.4 
Computed using nlm optimisation with 6 iterations (code = 1) 

[0, 0.434124342324438] U [0.640580807770818, 1]
```